# How Does Bayonetta shoot the guns on her feet?

Tags: bayonetta

I was just wondering this the other day.

Bayonetta has a gun attached to each shoe that she shoots for extreme awesomeness. How does she shoot these things? Is it like psychic, or are there some kind of special triggers in her shoes?

Comment: She is a witch, so I guess magic.

Comment: according to an admin from the bayonetta wiki

"She uses magic to remotely trigger weapons. Everything Bayonetta does that defies conventional logic is a literal case of "A Wizard did it!" in that she's a powerful Witch. "
I'd like to know more about this too.

Comment: Yeah, I really *wanted* to like Bayonetta, but this particular issue just made it all feel too unrealistic.  It's too bad, really - I'd been desperately in search of a solid, grounded title in which a mostly naked witch hides 1% of her body with her weaponized hair while ice-skating her way through a biblical martial arts music-video.

Comment: @Jaydles I think that comment just about answers the question

Comment: I believe she uses her hair to shoot.

Comment: Bayonetta wears hair from head to toe! Since her clothes are made of hair and she controls hair, she probably uses strands of hair to pull the trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I searched this because I'm working on a fanart of her and I haven't played the games but I can add a bit to the conversation even though it's super late

If you look at the guns in her hands in official art, the trigger-shaped-protrusion doesn't seem to actually be moveable. It's one large piece attached to the barrel and grip of the gun, not a small detached piece like a trigger normally would be. Now, the design is REALLY intricate and detailed, so this is probably not an accident.

This woman doesn't even need triggers to fire her guns. She uses 100% magic, even for the ones in her hands. She's so magic that she got custom made guns that don't even have triggers, so only she can fire them. Pretty badass imo.

[image: triggerless gun]

Comment: What a king....